# Select a range in Excel to paste a picture from CATIA v5 VBA

Tags: vba, image, automation, catia

I would like to add pictures in Excel in specifics cells using a CATIA macro.
Unfortunately, I can't achieve this, sometime my code works fine and sometime it crashes at the "select" line.

(For information, pictures are saved in a folder then I insert it in the sheet and then I want to put them in the right cell, this is where I have an issue.)

Here it is :

```
'DEFINE WHERE TO PASTE PICTURE AND PASTE
wb_BOM.Sheets(1).Shapes(i).Height = 56
wb_BOM.Sheets(1).Shapes(i).Cut
wb_BOM.Sheets(1).Range("E1").select
wb_BOM.Sheets(1).Paste
```

I also try without SELECT statement like this :

```
wb_BOM.Sheets(1).Paste Destination:=Range("E1")
```

But it also crashed... Do not hesitate if you have any idea !
Thanks !

- EDIT :

Sorry I forgot the error : The select method from range class has failed.

[image: Error]

Comment: You can't `Select` the range if the worksheet isn't active.

Comment: `wb_BOM.Sheets(1).Paste Destination:=wb_BOM.Sheets(1).Range("E1")` perhaps (untested).

Comment: Activate and select make errors when used with catia in this case, and I don't know why, yes I already tried it whit workbook and worksheet precision but it didn't worked as well. Thanks anyway for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not copying between worksheets you can try this code:

```
'DEFINE WHERE TO PASTE PICTURE AND PASTE
Sheets(1).Shapes(1).Height = 56
Dim targetcell As Range
Set targetcell = Sheets(1).Range("E1")
Sheets(1).Shapes(1).Top = targetcell.Top
Sheets(1).Shapes(1).Left = targetcell.Left
```

But I tried your code (version with select) and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: If the question is unclear then please do not answer it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @salamander Krajza, it works fine ! Sorry if I wasn't clear but I don't really understand why it works from Excel app but not from Catia... So not so easy to explain.